# Syntax errors with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax-error

```
USE AdventureWorks2019;
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.EmployeeGenderbyJobTitle
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EmployeeGenderbyJobTitle
    GO 

    CREATE TABLE #EmployeeGenderbyJobTitle
    (
        EmployeeID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Gender nchar(1),
        JobTitle nvarchar(50)
    )
    GO

    INSERT INTO #EmployeeGenderbyJobTitle (Gender, JobTitle)
        SELECT Gender, JobTitle
        FROM humanresources.employee AS e
    GO

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS FemaleEmployees, JobTitle
    FROM #EmployeeGenderbyJobTitle
    WHERE Gender = 'F' 
    GROUP BY JobTitle
    GO

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaleEmployees, JobTitle
    FROM #EmployeeGenderbyJobTitle
    WHERE Gender = 'M' 
    GROUP BY JobTitle
END;
```

When I keep the procedure's code by itself, the query runs no issue. Once I paste it in between begin and end the GO after drop table has a syntax error. I've tried rearranging the code, editing, playing with the semi colons and it won't go away. There's also a syntax error expecting conversation on the semicolon behind END that I can't figure out.

Comment: `GO` is a batch separator in SSMS, you can't use it in the middle of a procedure

Comment: Perhaps you are mistaking `GO` for a statement terminator; statements are terminated with a semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GO` signals the end of a batch in SQL Server so you can't use `go` in middle of a batch (a `procedure`, `function` etc.)

Reference [SQL Server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why you need the temp tables here in the first place. You could simplify this considerably with some conditional aggregation. This will return the count of gender by job title.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.EmployeeGenderbyJobTitle
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select Sum(case when e.Gender = 'M' then 1 end) as MaleEmployees
        , Sum(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end) as FemaleEmployees
        , e.JobTitle
    from humanresources.employee AS e
    group by e.JobTitle
END
```